# Theme suggestions for blocks in a region which has a dash in the name

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have a Region in the theme called `header-top`. As you may notice this region has a dash in the name instead of an underscore.

This theme is a sub-theme of a master theme called [`Framework`](https://drupal.org/project/Framework). I wanted to apply a certain template file to blocks in that region, so according to [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) page I've created a template file called `block--header-top.tpl.php` and cleared the cache. After re-loading the page a few times, I inspect the HTML to see if this particular template file is being applied, but all evidence suggests that it's still using `block.tpl.php`. I've tried using `template_preprocess_block` and `dpm`-ing out the `$variables` and in there I see an array `theme_hook_suggestions` which has the following values: `array(block__header-top, block__block, block__block__21)`. I've checked the existing template files and there's no template file named `block--block.tpl.php` or `block--block--21.tpl.php`. I've even tried to swap the dash with an underscore to be `block--header_top.tpl.php` but still no luck.

Finally I've switched the region name to become `header_top` and the renamed template `block--header_top.tpl.php` suddenly starts to take effect.

I'm wondering is there a certain naming convention for regions with dashes in the name? If so what would be the ways to try and find out what exactly the template name for this region should be? I'd like to not resort to renaming the region, as that may have a knock-on effect on modules and other template files which I may miss and mess up the production website.

Comment: Did you clear the caches after changing the dash to an underscore? That method should work just fine

Comment: I've cleared the cache on every step. The dash in the region name just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The dash wouldn't but the underscore does (in a standard install anyway). Do you have any contrib modules or an over-zealous theme installed that might be affecting it?

Comment: No as far as I know there aren't any. When I had the template file `block--header-top.tpl.php` it had `HEADER TOP` at the top of the file. Also I put `TEST` on top of `block.tpl.php` and before I renamed the region, I could only see `TEST` but after the region is renamed I see `HEADER TOP` being output. So the theming engine is definitely falling back to `block.tpl.php` in my theme folder. /scratches head

Comment: I just tried creating `block--sidebar_first.tpl.php` in a bare installation and that gets picked up as the documentation describes. It's got to be something your theme/site is doing differently

Comment: yea I think you misunderstood me @Clive, I'm having trouble with the opposite, ok with regions with underscores, but dashes seem to cause trouble with naming conventions when trying to create template files. Are dashes not allowed (or not recommended) in region names?

Comment: Yeah you need to use underscores, per the docs you linked to: _"An example of a region-specific template would be "block--sidebar_first.tpl.php"."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Theme suggestion docs you linked to the format for region-specific block templates go like this:

> An example of a region-specific template would be "block--sidebar_first.tpl.php"

It looks like Drupal flips `_` and `-` in theme suggestions so

> block__header-top

becomes

> block--header_top.tpl.php

(I knew it replaced `_` with `-` but I didn't know it was the other way round too; there may be more to it than that).

Comment: It looks like if your region name has an underscore, then it doesn't seem to matter if you use a dash or an underscore in the template name they both work. However if your region has a dash, then it doesn't seem to matter what you use... the template doesn't get picked up.